# Certificate chains on server and client

Tags: certificate, pki, self-signed-certificate

I have OpenSSL Certificate Authority, and I have generated Root certificate (self-signed), Intermediate certificate (signed by Root certificate), Server certificate (signed by Intermediate certificate) and Client certificate (signed by Intermediate certificate).

Server certificate is uploaded on my Cisco ASA (as Identity certificate). Also, I uploaded on my ASA Root certificate and Intermediate certificate.

Do I need to install Root and Intermediate certificates on my client computer. Or Client certificate is enough? (This is for VPN clients that should be authenticated with client certificates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple X509 keystores, some could be in separated places some could be in the same place/file.

- for each TLS/SSL listener you have an identity keystore. This contains the provate key of the service, the certificate for the service and all intermediate certificates that are part of the certificate chain that signed that certificate. The order should be service certificate, chain, private key. The root certificate should not be here.
- for each TLS/SSL client that needs to authenticate with a client certificate you have a similar identity keystore, containing  client certificate, intermediate certificates, client key. The root certificate should not be here.
- The trust keystore for the TLS/SSL client. This will authenticate the server certificate. It should contain only the root certificate of the service. It could contain also the intermediate certificates too. But those could be in another keystore used for intermediate certificates.
- The trust keystore for TLS/SSL server, used to authenticate each client connection to it's listener. This should contain the root certificate used to sign the client certificate.
- You may have a X509 keystore with revocated certificates.

In your case the root certificate for the client and the server are the same.

Comment: Ok, so both sides (server/ASA and client) must have Root and Intermediate certificates, plus server/ASA side has server certificate (Identity certificate) and client side have client certificate?

Comment: In short, yes. One encpoint (server or client) use the root CA and all intermediate to validate the remote endpoint certificate (client or, respectively, server). The client authenticate the server, and also the server authenticate the client, in your case. Usually, when a client certificate is not used, only the client validates the server certificate.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: Also when you do network captures to troubleshoot, search for ALERT protocol. This will help you understand the issue better. Who send the ALERT, for which message the ALERT was issued? Was ALERT send for failing certificate validation, key negotiation, ...

Comment: My answer is very generic and not tailored to Cisco ASA, but if you understand TLS in general, it will be much easier for you to solve this type of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Usually client certificates are issued by the root ca or intermediate to a client, so yes the clients need to have the root ca I think. Otherwise the certificate chain is incomplete and the client certificate cannot be validated.

Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client uses the Simple Certificate Enrollment Protocol (SCEP) to provision and renew a certificate as part of client authentication. Certificate enrollment using SCEP is supported by AnyConnect IPsec and SSL VPN connections to the ASA in the following ways:

SCEP Proxy: The ASA acts as a proxy for SCEP requests and responses between the client and the Certificate Authority (CA).

The CA must be accessible to the ASA, not the AnyConnect client, since the client does not access the CA directly.

Enrollment is always initiated automatically by the client. No user involvement is necessary.

Certificate Authority Requirements
All SCEP-compliant CAs, including IOS CS, Windows Server 2003 CA, and Windows Server 2008 CA, are supported.

So the VPN client installs the certificate. I would definitely recommend using SCEP for client certificates enrollment, that saves you a lot of work, deploying a certificate to each vpn user.